# indexedDB: What is "_proto_" doing in the database objects?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Has something changed in the way objects are stored in indexedDB, at least in Firefox?

I notice now in the developer tools storage tab that "_proto_" appears. I didn't think much about it until I observed odd behavior in my program that I couldn't figure out.

I thought that the objects were cloned before being written to the database such that, regardless of how they were created, they were independent.  For example, when the database is first created, some mapping objects are added; and, since several have the exact same layout/structure, a reference to a single object is used repeatedly as below.

When the page is loaded, the mapping data is read into RAM and used to manage the assignment of database keys. Unless I am really confused, it appears that prop_3 through prop_7 retain the common reference when later extracted from the database upon reload of the page, such that if one of the properties in prop_3 is updated, the same property is updated in prop_3 through prop_7.

Is this the way it is supposed to work? I expected prop_3 through prop_7 to no longer share a common reference after being written and read from the database.

If this is accurate, can the objects be written to the database in such a manner that these types of shared references will not be preserved? Of course, I realize that they can be assigned differently not using the reference to repeated_object; and, in fact, that corrects the specific issue for me. Thank you.

```
repeated_object = { ...property : value... };
os.add( { 'prop_1' : 1, 
          'prop_2' : 2,
          'prop_3' : repeated_object, 
          'prop_4' : repeated_object,
          'prop_5' : repeated_object,
          'prop_6' : repeated_object,
          'prop_7' : repeated_object  } );
```

Comment: What does the question about shared (and serialised) references have to do with `__proto__`?

Comment: I'm asking if `_proto_` is storing information about how an object was created such that, when later retrieved from the database, the object restored/created from the serialized form includes those same references. I thought that was not the case in the past and those references were not stored. Perhaps I simply never noticed before experiencing unexpected results in my code.

Comment: I'm not understanding how a reference to an object that was not written to the database is serialized. When that example object is retrieved from the database those last five properties are still treated as references to the same single object. Is that new to Firefox and is it done through `_proto_`? I thought only the data held in the object referenced would be serialized at the time it was written to the database and no references would remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is a reference to an object that was not written to the database serialized? When that example object is retrieved from the database those last five properties are still treated as references to the same single object.

Yes, that's expected. [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) does not use something like `JSON.stringify(value)` that would serialise an object multiple times if it was referenced multiple times. Instead, it uses [structured cloning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), which not only supports serialising more types, but also circular or shared references.

> Is that new to Firefox?

No, this should be consistent across all browsers.

> and is it done through `_proto_`?

No, not at all. That has nothing to do with it. The structured serialisation does not preserve prototype objects (other than the builtins).

Comment: Thank you. I guess I've just never encountered this before and have been sort of "getting away with'" a bad practice under a special case, that is, I've used references to other objects within objects being written to indexedDB but never multiple references to the same object or references within the same object.